Creating a probability version of the time-independent Schroedinger equation
I know, I know ... There is no advantage for creating a probability version of the time-independent Schroedinger equation because 1) it's no longer a linear eigenvalue equation; and 2) it's impossible to solve even for the simplest potentials.  I was just curious to see how it would be done and I did it with some basic calculus, certainly nothing fancy.
Here is a summary of what I did in one spatial dimension:

I defined $\psi(x) \, = \, A(x) \, e^{j\phi(x)}$ and $P(x) \, = \, |\psi(x)|^2 \, = \, A^{2}(x)$
I substituted $\psi(x)$ into the time-independent Schroedinger equation
$\psi$ is a complex quantity, but $A$, $\phi$, and $P$ are real quantities $\rightarrow$ we obtain two equations:

$-\frac{\hbar^{2}}{2m} \left[\frac{1}{2} \frac{d^{2} ln{P}}{dx^{2}} + \frac{1}{4} \left(\frac{d \, ln{P}}{dx}\right)^{2} - \left(\frac{d\phi}{dx}\right)^{2}\right] \, = \, E - V$
and
$\frac{d^{2}\phi}{dx^{2}} + \frac{d\, ln{P}}{dx} \frac{d\phi}{dx} \, = \, 0$ .

I solved the second equation first because it's easy.  I obtained:

$\frac{d\phi}{dx} \, = \, \frac{C}{P}$, where $C$ is a constant.

This solved second equation is substituted into the first equation so that it only contains $P$

$-\frac{\hbar^{2}}{2m} \left[\frac{1}{2} \frac{d^{2} ln{P}}{dx^{2}} + \frac{1}{4} \left(\frac{d \, ln{P}}{dx}\right)^{2} - \left(\frac{C}{P}\right)^{2}\right] \, = \, E - V$ .
Now that I have the preliminaries out of the way, I come to something that I find confusing.  I rearrange the second solved equation to obtain $P \frac{d\phi}{dx} \, = \, C$, a constant of the motion.  But, from what I remember from my quantum mechanics classes many years ago, the probability times the phase gradient is the probability current $J$.  If this is the case, why is it constant?  I thought that it wasn't supposed to be constant, in general.
Thinking that I made a mistake, I decided to solve the first equation for $P$ for two simple cases, the free particle and the infinite potential well.  Actually, for both cases I solved for $\psi$, calculated $P$ from it (including energy levels), and substituted it back into the first equation for $P$ to see if they satisfy it.  As I said above, the first $P$ equation is impossible to solve.  But everything checked out.
I'm at a loss.  Does anyone else have an insight into this apparent inconsistency?

Can you clarify how you solved the second equation exactly?

Hint: Compare with the Madelung equations.

@Ruffolo Solving the second equation is fairly straightforward.  Rearranging to get the second derivative over the first derivative, it just the logarithmic derivative of the first derivative.  Since there are now perfect derivatives on both sides of the equation, you get the phase gradient as a function of probability.

@Qmechanic You're the second person to suggest this.  I will take a look.

Thank you for clarification. Indeed, Reading the answer below I noticed that you started with time Independent Schrodinger equation. Stationery state means constant current. If you try it through time dependent Schrodinger equation, you'll get more general probability current

@Ruffolo You're talking about constant in time, but I'm talking about constant in space.  Are you saying that it's not possible for the probability current to have spatial variability without temporal variability?

I didn't check the calculations, but in the continuity equation, we usually have the divergence operator in the current term. If temporal term is zero, the current should be divergenceless. However, in a 1D system, it implies that it will not vary in space. Try it with 3D Schrodinger equation

It would be cleaner to use the Madelung transformation. Normally, probability alone is not enough to close the equations, you need an additional degree of freedom related to the phase. Physically, you know that phase captures the distribution of momentum via the Fourier transform. This is why you introduce  velocity:
$$
\psi = \sqrt\rho e^{i\phi}\\
\rho = |\psi|^2\quad v = \partial_x\phi = \frac{\psi^*\partial_x\psi-\psi\partial_x\psi^*}{2i|\psi|^2}
$$
Your first equation is simply Bernoulli's equation and your second the continuity equation. You can indeed solve it as:
$$
j = \rho v
$$
with $j$ a constant flux. However, for eigenstates, this simplifies further as you even have detailed balance. The means that $j = v = 0$. This is because up to a global phase, energy eigenstates have real wavefunctions due to non degeneracy (this follows from Sturm-Liouville theory). Therefore, in Bernoulli's equation, you just need to balance potential and pressure (Bohm potential):
$$
V+p = E \\
p = -\frac{\hbar^2}{2m\sqrt{\rho}}\frac{d^2\sqrt\rho}{dx^2}
$$

To be honest I think that mine is cleaner, but I will look at the Madelung transform.  So you're saying that my constant probability current is correct?  Even for a case like quantum tunneling.
